# NVD3.js Y axis Minimim

Tags: javascript

For some reason I am have having a hard time finding a way to set the start of the y axis.  I want the y axis to start at 0. right now it is starting at 15

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

        chart.xAxis
            .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });
        chart.x2Axis
            .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });

        chart.yAxis
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
        chart.y2Axis
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

        d3.select('#chart svg')
                .datum(
                    [
                        {
                            key : 'Current' ,
                            color : '#2ca02c',
                            values : [
                                { x:01112014 , y:15 },
                                ...
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            key : 'Backlog' ,
                            color : '#ff7f0e',
                            values : [
                                { x:01112014 , y:50 },
                                ...
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                )
                .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `forceY`:

```
chart.lines.forceY([ 0 ]);  // main chart
chart.lines2.forceY([ 0 ]); // view finder chart
```